# Como eu posso fazer com que um programa seja encerrado ao digitar um espaço vazio (' ') no python

Tags: python, while

Como eu posso fazer um laço de repetição while parar quando o usuário inserir um espaço em branco (" ")?

Tentei fazer assim:

```
while num != '':
    num = int(input("Insira um número: "))
```

Porém a variável não é um número inteiro, então ao inserir um espaço em branco, ela apresenta um erro.

O certo é ao inserir o espaço em branco, ela continuar e mostra o resultado.

Comment: Espaço vazio é meio dúbio. Digitar um caractere espaço seguido de um ENTER ou apenas um ENTER? Talvez apenas converter para numérico a string digitada tiver comprimento maior que zero e se não for um espaço?

Comment: é pro usuario ficar digitando por exemplo:
1
3
5
e ai quando ele nao digitar nada, apenas dar o enter, mostrar o resultado final

Comment: Então não é para ele digitar um espaço? Neste caso basta verificar se a entrada é uma string vazia.

Comment: @GustavoCarvalho A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se deveria fazer assim, mas se quiser insistir teria que fazer as operações em dois passos, trata como texto e se não for aquilo então trata como número, mas o ideal seria tratar um erro de digitação, já era importante antes, fazendo desta forma fica mais importante ainda, algo assim:

```
while True:
    entrada = input("Insira um número: ")
    if entrada == ' ':
        break
    try:
        num = int(entrada)
        print(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Dado inválido')

print('fim')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/U4ExCx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ctfiyivz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ExitChar.py).

Comment: Também não achei uma forma muito legal, mas meu professor quer assim então a gente faz